# get the alarm interval

Tags: android

Is it possible from code to discover the interval a previous alarm was set to - is there an alarm.info type of facility giving the interval?   After setting my alarm from a service the service closes but the alarm of course exists outside the program.   If I restart the app can I tell the interval of an alarm previously set?

Comment: Why not just save it with SharedPreferences, then you can read it back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to cancel it instead.

Build the same PendingIntent as if you did not care then call...

```
mAlarmManager.cancel(myPendingIntent);
```

... before rescheduling it.

Still, I'm interested by a better solution.